# Drupal + AMFPHP + Simplenews. Is it possible?

Tags: php, flash, drupal, amfphp

I'm integrating Drupal with Flash using AMFPHP as a service.

Everything works as expected with view.get and node.get

The problem is that now I need to integrate the newsletter making flash "talk" with [simplenews](http://drupal.org/node/197057) since simplenews works as a module I can't find a way to let them talk.

What I would need is to send an email address and get an ok if the mail has been stored and an error if the email is already registered, is this even possible with my current setup? Alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should be helpful: http://drupal.org/node/221521